# SQL Select Query with like condtion

Tags: sql

[image]

I have to select Query

```
Table:- TableName
column-1:- FirstColumn (text)
Column-2:- SecondColumn (4-digitnumber,4-digitnumber)

like text = "Checking"
like Number = 2261 2265 2630 2659

Select  * 
From    TableName 
Where   FirstColumn '%checking%' 
And     SecondColumn'%2261%' 
Or      SecondColumn'%2265%' 
Or      SecondColumn'%2630%'
```

Need to select the CHECKING TEXT where Second Column 2261 and other three numeric.

Comment: What is the *datatype* of the `SecondColumn`?  Is it an `INT` or is it a `VARCHAR`?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to wrap all the ORs in a single bracket. also, use `LIKE`

```
Select  * 
From    TableName 
Where   FirstColumn like '%checking%' 
And     ( SecondColumn like '%2261%' 
Or      SecondColumn like '%2265%' 
Or      SecondColumn like '%2630%');
```

Comment: SecondColumn values. (2630,2665) same row. its not working

Comment: Which dbms are you using? what is the type of SecondColumn?

Comment: datatype varchar(500)

Comment: @JOhn which database?

Comment: Mircosoft Sql server

Comment: @John It should work as is. Can you post sample data on which it is not working and what output you expect?

Comment: please look on the image